# Как ввести строку с однобайтовыми символами и вывести эту строку в двухбайтовом формате

Tags: c

Я пытался использовать функцию MultiByteToWideChar. Точнее мне нужно это выполнить с её помощью.

```
char str [] = "poproboval";
    int strSize = sizeof(str);
    int count = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, strSize, NULL, 0);
    nWChar = nWChar * sizeof(wchar_t);
    wchar_t wstr[count];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, strSize, &wstr[0], count);
    printf("\nUnicode:%s",wstr);
```

Но у меня выводить только первую букву.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот такой код не работает

```
wchar_t data[] = L"test";

printf("%s", data);
```

вот такой код работает

```
wchar_t data[] = L"test";

printf("%ls", data);
```

В общем используйте `%ls`

Comment: Да, всё заработало, теперь буду знать

Comment: у вас вывод был для `char`, а в `char*` юникод ASCII символов выглядит как [1 байт кода символа, 0x00] - поэтому вам и выводило как строку первый символ (1 байт UNICODE символа ASCII совпадает с кодом ASCII символа, а второй байт был 0, т.е. концом строки